# Vue.js link in a tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I link properly to another page with vue 2 ? I have a bootstrap table and every row has to link somewhere else how could I do this? If I do it like this:

```
<tr @click="url(forum)">data</tr>

url(forum) {
  window.location.href = '/berichten/' + forum.slug;    
}
```

I can't add another `@click` in that row like this:

```
<td @click="destroy(forum)">forum</td>
```

**NOTE: I do not use Vue.js router.**

Any help would be much appreciated

**--EDIT--**

When I click on the `<td @click="destroy(forum)">` it goes to the `url(forum);` function instead of my `destroy(forum)` function.

Comment: Can you expand on "can't add"? What happens when you add it? Does the click handler not work? Does the click handler of the `<tr>` also work? etc.

Comment: Consider using a regular `<a>` element with a `href` attribute instead of adding a click handler on some random element, if all you want to do is to navigate to another URL.

Comment: @AtesGoral could you give an example? Already tried that but it dit not work for me.

Comment: `<tr><td><a :href="\`/bericthen/${forum.slug}\`">data</a></td></tr>`

Comment: @AtesGoral yes but then I've to add that to every  ```<td>``` right? Is it not possible to add this to the ```<tr>```?

Comment: Yes, then you need to add a click handler. You could in theory still use an absolutely positioned `<a>` element that covers the entire row, but that could be overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prevent event propagation on your nested click handler by using the ".stop" [modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers):

```
<td @click.stop="destroy(forum)">forum</td>
```

Demo (non-Vue.js):

https://jsfiddle.net/atesgoral/xgn92eb0/

Comment: Well played seems you beat me to the gun.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your `td` click declaration to have `.stop` so that the click event isn't bubbled up to the tr

It would look like this:

```
<td @click.stop="destroy(forum)">forum</td>
```